# Toggle leave the first open and the rest

Tags: jquery, toggle, css-selectors

How can I make the first category open and the rest is closed via toggle? h4 is the element that should stay and the div after that should toggle. Thanks in advance for your help

```
<div class="pb_dimension-filters" id="divRefinementLeft">
    <div class="pb_dim-filter">
        <h4>Category 1</h4>
        <div class="pb_dim-filter-list-container">
            <ul>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pb_dim-filter">
        <h4>Category 2</h4>
        <div class="pb_dim-filter-list-container">
            <ul>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pb_dim-filter">
        <h4>Category 3</h4>
        <div class="pb_dim-filter-list-container">
            <ul>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now fully simulating a toggle effect

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divRefinementLeft > div > div").hide();

    $("#divRefinementLeft > div").bind("click", function(){
        if($("div", $(this)).hasClass("v"))
        {
            $("#divRefinementLeft > div > div").removeClass("v").hide();
        }
        else {
            $("#divRefinementLeft > div > div").removeClass("v").hide();
            $("div", $(this)).addClass("v").show();
        }
    }) ;
});
```

Comment: h4 is the element that should stay and the div after that should toggle

Comment: Then its your browser, when I click on a header, I see a 1. appear under. Maybe your browser doesnt display empty li. What are you using?

Comment: Im using chrome v35.0

Comment: Maybe you wanted a real toggle, so I updated again... but if your code doesnt work, check if your Javascript is activated. Chrome should run this with no problem at all.

Comment: updated to make the click more visible: [my code playing the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3sdS/8/)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I ended up using

```
$j(".pb_dim-filter > div").addClass("closed-filter");
$j("#divRefinementLeft > div:first > div").removeClass("closed-filter");
$j(".pb_dim-filter > h4").click(function(){
    $j(this).siblings("div.pb_dim-filter-list-container").toggleClass("closed-filter");
});
```